# Three.js - Keep an object's location static with respect to the camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am wondering how I could keep an object's location static with regard to the camera.
I.e. I have two objects, one which I want to observe from multiple angles using the trackball camera and another one which should always remain static with regard to the current camera view.

E.g. overlaying a mesh (to be observed from multiple angles using the trackball camera) on an image (static position with regard to trackball camera).

Hope I explained my question alright.

Thanks for any advice :)

Currently I have:

```
object.position.copy( camera.position );
object.rotation.copy( camera.rotation );
object.updateMatrix();
```

**EDIT**

I figured it out:

```
object.position.copy( camera.position );
object.rotation.copy( camera.rotation );
object.updateMatrix();
object.translateZ( - 10 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different methods.

If you want to keep an object static in the camera's field of view:

```
 camera.lookAt(object);
```

Another method to copy all of an object's transforms onto the camera:

```
 //add camera as a child of object
 object.add(camera);
```